# Are there any software libraries for backtesting FX algorithms against tick data?

Tags: backtesting, fx

I've read [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8896/except-zipline-are-there-any-other-pythonic-algorithmic-trading-library-i-can-c), however it doesn't appear as if any of those libraries work for FX data. A Google search for `python forex backtesting` turns up [this project](https://github.com/vighneshiyer/forex-backtester-python), however I think it needs quite a bit more development before it can be considered useful.

As far as I can tell the two most promising projects are [Zipline](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline) and [Quantlib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml), but again no FX support.

After a bit more searching it looks like my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10886/are-there-python-algorithmic-trading-libraries-supporting-forex).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [Backtesting.py](https://kernc.github.io/backtesting.py/), but the website says it only works with OHLC data.

Maybe you can **group your tick data into 1-second buckets**, afterwards finding that all sorts of tools apply.